# call one workflow from another workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I'm using SharePoint designer 2010, 
I have created 2 workflow (Workflow A and Workflow B), 
and now I want to call/start workflow B from workflow a.
how can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When workflow A ends you can update a status column or a tracking column that will trigger workflow b to initiate.  Prior to having a commercial workflow engine, I would have a main status column that drives workflow A and in workflow B, I'd have a condition like if Workflow A tracking column = X and workflow tracking column B = Y, do something. Else update a column so that workflw A refires.

Answer (score 3):

In designer workflow, there is no option for calling another workflow... Refer this,

http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/

This provides you extra workflow actions like calling workflow etc.

Comment: call another workflow in spdactivities has two parameters that users understanding hardly what they are? and first one is workflow name or second one. ? or this is a workflow name in other Document library (or list ) or in our current working list. there are no clear help document or sample there! please refer us to another samples ... that describe this clearly. or you describe it here by pictures... or link to download pdf or link to page in that site's thread